# iOS Safari Video recording Blob/FileReader bug

Tags: javascript, video, blob, mobile-safari, filereader

my problem is, I have script, that take video from camera. On my iPhone, there is problem, I can't use BLOB as URL for `<video></video>`, so I used FileReader, that makes base64 from BLOB. But I found another problem. When I take video in portrait mode, the captured video is in landscape mode, is so much wide. I need rotate that video to portrait mode. I don't know, if I have mistake in Blob or FileReader code. Can you help me please? Thanks.

This is my HTML Code:

```
<video autoplay="true" id="cameraVideo" playsinline webkit-playsinline>
```

This is my Javascript Code:

```
var video = document.querySelector("#cameraVideo");
var mode = "rear";
var mediaRecorder;
var chunks = [];
if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: { facingMode: "environment" } }).then(function (stream) {
                video.srcObject = stream;
                mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
    }).catch(function (err0r) {
                alert("Something went wrong!");
    });
}
$(".camera").find(".take").on("touchstart mousedown", function() {
    mediaRecorder.start();
    mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(ev) {
        chunks.push(ev.data);
    }
});
$(".camera").find(".take").on("touchend mouseup", function() {
    mediaRecorder.stop();
    mediaRecorder.onstop = (ev)=>{
    var blob = new Blob(chunks, { 'type' : 'video/mp4' });
    chunks = [];
    var videoURL = webkitURL.createObjectURL(blob);
    if(video.srcObject) video.srcObject.getTracks().forEach(t => t.stop());
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(blob); 
        reader.onloadend = function() {
            document.getElementById("savevideo").src = reader.result;
            document.getElementById("savevideo").play();                
        }
    }
});
```

Pictures:

When video is recording :
[image: When video is recording]

When video is recorded :
[image: When video is recorded]

Comment: I have the same issue, I only found this bug report which adds to this case, but no activity on solving it yet. https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=198912

Comment: Two issues: ondataavailable is calling after mediaRecorder.stop() and getting blob:0 in ev.data inside ondataavailable function. Any solution??

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, have you found any solution?